# Exclude field in array of subdocument in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two document

`image` document:

```
{_id:123,user:{user_sub_docuemnt},thumb:'dqwdqwdqwdw'}
```

`post` document:

```
{_id:444,
 user:{user_sub_document},
 attach:[{_id:123,
          user:{user_sub_docuemnt},
          thumb:'dqwdqwdqwdw'}
        ]
 }
```

the `user_sub_document` contain `password` field, so I need to exclude that field.

This is what i have so far:

```
Post.aggregate([
        {$match: {'user._id': {$in:idArr}}},

        {$project:{content:1,attach:1,pub_date:1,'user.avatar':1}},
    ],function(err,posts){
        if(err){
            throw err
        }else{
            res.send(posts)
        }
    })
```

this will only limit user in Post level, there is another user_sub_document in attach array,so I tried this

```
{$project:{content:1,attach:1,'attach.user':0,pub_date:1,'user.avatar':1}},
```

this will give me an error `The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported for exclusion`

please help me with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple `find()` statement:

```
Post.find({"user._id":{$in:idArr}},
          {"content":1,
           "user.avatar":1,
           "pub_date":1,
           "attach.user.avatar":1})
```

In case you choose to aggregate for some reason, You could modify your `aggregation pipeline` as below:

- `$match` the records with specific user Ids.
- `$project` only the required fields.

code:

```
Post.aggregate([
{$match:{"user._id":{$in:idArr}}},
{$project:{"user.avatar":1,
           "attach.user.avatar":1,
           "pub_date":1,
           "content":1}}],function(err,resp){
           // handle response
         })
```

Comment: Nice,It works. but this won't return the post that don't have attach, I think is because `{$unwind:"$attach"},`, any idea how to fix this???

Comment: @paynestrike - I have modified my solution. Please check. The `$unwind` is not necessary.